How to view the crash information in .ips file from Xcode console
I'm trying to get the crash information from .ips file and print the information in Xcode console.
For now, I can see the .ips file by selection Window -> Device and Simulator -> Open Recent logs. This will open the folder that contains the .ips and we can see the details of the crash.
Is there any way to get this information in .ips file within Xcode and print it in the console?
I have tried using Mertric Kit to get the crash details, but it's not as detailed in .ips file

Rename .ips file to .crash file extension and then try to view information using Xcode. If dSYM is available, Xcode should be able to symbolicate else can follow below steps for symbolification.
If dSYM file is available, then one can use symbolicatecrash providing it with path to .ips and dSYM.
One can check if symbolicatecrash is available by running below command on terminal. This will result in the path for it.
find /Applications -name symbolicatecrash

The path most like should be like
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

Executing symbolicatecrash required environment variable DEVELOPER_DIR to be setup as pre-requisite. Set it up like:
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

After this symbolicatecrash command can be run providing path for .ips and dSYM like below:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash path/to/app.ips path/to/app.dSYM > SymbolicatedReport.crash

Generated SymbolicatedReport.crash can be opened with Xcode to view crash information.
